# Why does my heading disappear in IE7 and change color in FF?

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer-7, html-heading

This is probably an easy fix, but I'm stumped. Here's the URL: [http://urgent.mchenry.edu](http://urgent.mchenry.edu/)

First off, underneath the urgent.mchenry.edu text box in the header is an h2 w/ class="caps" and text that says "Official McHenry County College Update". However, it absolutely disappears in IE7. Gone.

I tweaked the ie.css with !important declarations, but still, no go. What gives?

Secondly, in FF, the same h2 has some weird a:hover states, despite the fact that there's NOT an anchor tag in the source code, but FF inserts its own. Use Firebug and see what I'm talking about.

Any help on the above two points would be greatly appreciated. BTW, I'm running XP/FF 3.5 and IE8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the hover state is easy to fix - your closing tag on the urgent.mchenry.edu link is `<a/>` instead of `</a>`.  I suspect this may fix your other issues too.